# Error compiling VS Code extension with dependency on another extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've built a VS Code extension that wants to re-use some code from another extension. It doesn't compile because of duplicate `vscode` declarations on the build path. Any idea if this is a real issue or if I can tweak my build path to make it work?

The error is as follows:

```
lerna ERR! > vscode-sample-with-dependency@1.0.0 build /.../import-cost/packages/vscode-sample-with-dependency
lerna ERR! > tsc -p ./
lerna ERR!
lerna ERR! node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts(11,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'version'.
lerna ERR! node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts(239,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Position'.
lerna ERR! node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts(358,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Range'.
lerna ERR! node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts(459,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Selection'.
lerna ERR! node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts(504,3): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Keyboard'.
... and many more ...
```

Sample project is available here:
https://github.com/guw/import-cost ([commit c184a4c2](https://github.com/guw/import-cost/commit/c184a4c2b09ab39a342d65547c67352724be3565))

To reproduce:

1. clone
2. npm install
3. npm run build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this mapping into your `tsconfig.json`

```
    "baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
        "vscode": ["node_modules/vscode"]
     }
```

This problem seems to be a result of this issue.  See here for reference.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6496#issuecomment-351435136